# binary search in sorted array

Tags: arrays, binary-search

Hi i am trying to carry out a binary search in a sorted array by using the input by the user by means of a text box.

This is my code:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace arra3 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int[] arr = { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };

        int low, high, user_input, mid;

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            user_input = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

            while (low <= high)
            {
                mid = (low + high) / 2;


                if (arr[mid] < user_input)
                {
                    low = mid + 1;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (arr[mid] > user_input)
                {
                    high = mid - 1;
                    continue;
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(mid.ToString());
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("-1".ToString());

        }
    } 
}
```

But I keep getting either -1 as an output or enter in an infinite loop of 0 if i enter a zero.

Any help please?

Comment: why don't you make a tree structure first? - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @MCPol the answer was updated

Comment: @MCPol , please mark your question as answered (accept my answer). Please read the rules here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have initialized `low` and `high` variables and added `return` statement after the match is found.
Here is the corrected code (notice the comments):

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace arra3 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int[] arr = { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 };

        int low, high, user_input, mid;

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            user_input = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            low = 0;  // <- HERE
            high = arr.Length;  // <- HERE

            while (low <= high)
            {
                mid = (low + high) / 2;


                if (arr[mid] < user_input)
                {
                    low = mid + 1;
                    continue;
                }
                else if (arr[mid] > user_input)
                {
                    high = mid - 1;
                    continue;
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(mid.ToString());
                    return;  // <- HERE
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("-1".ToString());

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry took long to answer. Yes it did work. Thank you for your help. Greatly appreciated

Comment: @MCPol, please mark it as an answer, if it helped you